# DataFrame reduce by

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Need help on ... converting multiple rows into single row by keys. group by advise appreciated. Using pyspark Version:2

```
l = (1,1,'', 'add1'  ),
    (1,1,'name1', ''),
    (1,2,'', 'add2'),
    (1,2,'name2', ''),
    (2,1,'', 'add21'),
    (2,1,'name21', ''),
    (2,2,'', 'add22'),
    (2,2,'name22', '')

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['Key1', 'Key2','Name', 'Address'])
df.show()
+----+----+------+-------+
|Key1|Key2|  Name|Address|
+----+----+------+-------+
|   1|   1|      |   add1|
|   1|   1| name1|       |
|   1|   2|      |   add2|
|   1|   2| name2|       |
|   2|   1|      |  add21|
|   2|   1|name21|       |
|   2|   2|      |  add22|
|   2|   2|name22|       |
+----+----+------+-------+
```

I am stuck looking for output like

```
+----+----+------+-------+
|Key1|Key2|  Name|Address|
+----+----+------+-------+
|   1|   1| name1 |   add1|
|   1|   2| name2 |   add2|
|   2|   1| name21|  add21|
|   2|   2| name22|  add22|
+----+----+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Key1` and `Key2`, and take the maximum value from `Name` and `Address`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupBy(['Key1', 'Key2']).agg(
    F.max(df.Name).alias('Name'), 
    F.max(df.Address).alias('Address')
).show()
+----+----+------+-------+
|Key1|Key2|  Name|Address|
+----+----+------+-------+
|   1|   1| name1|   add1|
|   2|   2|name22|  add22|
|   1|   2| name2|   add2|
|   2|   1|name21|  add21|
+----+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: appreciate for your response Thank you!!,